# titanium studio using html tags in strings.xml

Tags: ios, iphone, internationalization, titanium-mobile

In titanium iOS app how can I display string from strings.xml containing html tags.

Following is the string

**Rashad Al Moosa\nPartner\neZayed**\n\nRashad Al Moosahas a wealth of commercial expertise

What u see in bold does not appear in iOS app only if I remove bold tag string gets displayed.

Does titanium support any html tags within strings.xml?

Answer (score 0):

With iOS:

look at : [enter link description here](http://www.tidev.io/2014/11/13/using-basic-html-in-labels-on-ios-like-android/)

On Android:

```
<string name="mr">
<![CDATA[
<b>Rashad Al Moosa<br/>Partner<br>eZayed<br><br></b>
Rashad Al Moosahas a wealth of commercial expertise
]]>
</string>
```

Comment: nope does not work I am using titanium studio for iOS app.(i guess this is for native android) .

Comment: you're right, it's more for android. Have you tried using &lt;b&gt; for bold tag for example ?

Comment: I can't get it working in SDK 4.1.0.GA ... `<string name="description"><![CDATA[dd<b>abc</b>ff]]></string>`